# Craft 3: Cache element query or variable assignment

Tags: templating, cache, craft3

Is it possible to cache a variable assignment and/or an element query with TWIG in Craft 3? With Yii2 this is possible, but is there a wrapper to TWIG?

2 use cases:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.someThingVerySlowHere() %}
{% set myObject = customVerySlowTwigFunction(...) %}
```

Why would I want to do that? Let's assume I have 2 blocks in my page, both make use of the variables assigned above, then I can not cache this within the block itself (where the `{% cache %}` tag belongs, unless I assign/query twice.

Answer (score -1):

The request makes sense, but I thought that Craft did some magic to make sure that a duplicate query/variable-assignment wasn't an issue by re-using the query internally. I have *no idea* why I think that though.

Comment: but this would only work on queries, not function calls...

Comment: of course functions could cache itself... but it's nice to see it in the template